# jQuery $.ajax loop stalls supposedly asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

I need to make multiple HTTP requests to an external server via $.ajax and as far as my understanding goes, this should be asynchronous meaning that the multiple HTTP requests do not wait until the preceding request is complete before executing another one.

However, I have found that in practice, this does not hold up. I have this function:

```
function gethttp(i, v) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("raw", v.raw);
    $.ajax({
        url: "gethttp.php?cache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            renderdata(i, data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            renderdata(i, {found: "0", bibs:""});
            apply(i, "danger", false);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
}
```

I then use $.each to iterate through an array `requests` which passes variables `i` and `v` to `gethttp()` for the HTTP request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(requests, function(i, v) {
        gethttp(i, v);
    });
});
```

However, this process can take up to 5 minutes depending on the size of my `requests` array which can range in length anywhere between 5-500 items. My thought process was that this should take roughly 2 seconds because each HTTP request by itself takes that long, but by looping through it like the above, the requests are executed sequentiality and the entire process takes forever.

Do I need to go deploy this with node.js in order to get parallel processing? If so, I would really appreciate  good tutorial on the subject. Can I do this with jQuery itself without resorting to node.js?

Thanks

Comment: If you're executing this in a browser and all the requests are to the same host, then the browser will limit how many requests you can make to one host at a time.  And, a given server probably can't actually process hundreds of requests at the exact same time either.

Comment: This was what I was suspecting. Would node.js compensate for this limitation?

Comment: node would let you make more simultaneous connections to the same host, but can't do anything about how many actual requests the target web server can handle at once.

Comment: I would think this would be more of an issue 10 years ago - but those many requests at the same time is nothing compared to the amount of traffic that runs through highly ranked websites that generate 1000's of HTTP requests at any given point. I'm sure there is a way to multithread or parallel process.

Comment: It depends entirely upon what kind of server is serving the requests and what each request is tasked with doing.  Yes some big clustered iron can handle lots of requests, but you didn't' say anything about what the target server is so I'm mentioning that as a possible issue too.  Plus if the requests have to all hit a database, the database could be a bottleneck too.  It all depends upon the target server configuration.

Comment: 8 core CPU with 1 GB of RAM and and around 10% overhead on the RAM and 1% on the CPU so its not a tasking process. I'm starting to see your point though.

Comment: It still depends upon the web server configuration.  Is it your own server that's the target of these requests?  If so, what kind of web server configuration is it?  Is each request hitting a database?  And, if so, change your requests so you can pass all the data you want in one request and return all the data in one request rather than making 500 repeated requests.

Comment: Its a Linux VPS running nginx - no database

Comment: Are you just serving static files?

Comment: Its going to my server but I'm CURLing from an external server in that file - thats a public API - I  don't think it has a bottleneck.

Comment: I was thinking - instead of sending looped ajax requests, just send a single request to node.js server and multi-thread it from there to bypass the bottleneck in the browser.